# R can't install ggplot2 package

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wanted to install the ggplot2 package using:

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
```

and I got R this message:

```
>  install.packages("ggplot2")
Installation du package dans ‘C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3’
(car ‘lib’ n'est pas spécifié)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/ggplot2_3.4.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 4294341 bytes (4.1 MB)
downloaded 1.4 MB

Warning in install.packages :
  downloaded length 0 != reported length 0
Warning in install.packages :
  URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/ggplot2_3.4.2.zip': Timeout of 60 seconds was reached
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  download from 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/ggplot2_3.4.2.zip' failed
Warning in install.packages :
  le téléchargement du package ‘ggplot2’ a échoué
> `
```

Then I tried the URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/ggplot2_3.4.2.zip' and I downloaded the ggplot2 zip file. I tried to install from the zip file using :

```
`install.packages("C:/Users/User/Downloads/Compressed/ggplot/ggplot2_3.4.2.zip", repos = NULL)`
```

I still got an error message. I have also downloaded and installed Rtools but I still cannot install the GGPLOT2 package. I restarted R  then and make sure to run `install.package("ggplot2")` before anything else. I got error message again

Can you help to solve the problem, please ? Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi does this help? https://community.rstudio.com/t/unable-to-install-package-in-r-studio-warning-unable-to-access-index-for-repository/15930/19

Comment: Hello, I try their answers but it is still not working

Comment: @FréjusteFassin have you tried to increase the timeout option?  You can type this to increase the timeout to 5 minutes for the download: `options(timeout = max(300, getOption("timeout")))`

Comment: Thank you for your message. But finally I unstalled again my R version and download the R 4.3.1 and when I tryed to insatll the ggplot2 package it asked me to installed colorspace then I install the colorspace and now it works

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current development version of `ggbiplot` with

```
remotes::install_github("friendly/ggbiplot")
```